# How should I structure my JavaFX project to work when pulled from GitHub?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, javafx

I am having a bit of trouble structuring my JavaFX program in a way so that the person using my project won't have to compile pieces of my code to make it work. Currently, my code is structured in this way.

```
Project
->Gui.fxml
->Gui.java
->GuiController.java
->Package
    ->SomeClass.java
    ->SomeClass.java
    ->SomeClass.java
    ->SomeClass.java
```

The way my project is currently structured, anyone that wishes to use my code will have to compile the source code within the package folder into class files, then the controller needs to be compiled into a class file, and then project needs to be run. I get the feeling that not only is this bad practice, but that there is a simpler, more elegant, professional, and systematic way of structuring the code. I could not figure out how to do this using eclipse. I would appreciate any assistance, or at least if someone could point me in the direction of some resources I could read.

Thanks!

Comment: Typically you would use some sort of build system: maven, gradle, ant etc. and define the build process there.

Comment: The structure of your package doesn't really have anything to do with Git per se.  From what I see, all of the files would need to be versioned by Git.  You can think of Git as a silent observer which takes snapshots of your entire project.  How that project gets structured, and how optimal it is, is determined by you.

Comment: @1615903 I've heard maven used before, but I never really knew what context. I guess that makes sense. I'll have to do some research on how it works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That makes sense. If I rearrange the project structure, will git recognize the files as the same? That's refactoring right? Will github track moving files?

Comment: You can certainly move files around, with the possible caveat that some history may be lost in Git.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, that's good to know. Thanks!

Comment: If you have never used any build system, learn gradle rather than maven :P

Comment: @shash678 Thanks! I'll check it out!